# During importing a previous export of products Configurable products don't have simple products any more

Tags: configurable-product, import, importexport, export

I exported all products and then cleared all products. When I try to import the same products, I can do this, but configurable products don't have th associated simple products any more. What happens here, and what is the proper way to export/import Configurable products?